# Add row to an Excel table using Flow skip columns values

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, microsoft-flow

I'm trying to export a SharePoint list to table in a specific worksheet in Excel (both created in the same Flow), when I try to add a row to the table it doesn't add all the values to the row as you can see below:
[image]

Here is the flow:

[image]

And once I run it, the input in `Add a row into a table` is correct, but the output is not.
[image]